# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList

Tags: android, unsatisfiedlinkerror, myo

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld, PID: 16803
      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.thalmic-myosdk-0.10.0_67ebee2ca6da7cdf5465641b2d9b682feb72b565-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libgesture-classifier.so"
          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
          at com.thalmic.myo.scanner.Scanner.<clinit>(Scanner.java:31)
          at com.thalmic.myo.Hub.init(Hub.java:201)
          at com.thalmic.android.sample.helloworld.HelloWorldActivity.onCreate(HelloWorldActivity.java:163)
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5979)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'

Can anyone please help me?

I'm having problem trying to connect Android with Myo by bluetooth.

I think it is an version problem, but I'm kind of lost with this error.

Comment: Why is the link there?  Is there any code you can post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: sorry guys this is my first post, no it isn't a duplicate of this link, and the code is correct i think it is an build graddle problem

Comment: @IanAragão Maybe not the best use of the duplicate flag. Basically I was linking you to a post on what steps to take when your app crashes.